# How to deal with the Asynchronous run of Android in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, arraylist

I am making an app for android with firebase. What I am trying to do is that every node has a level number:

```
User---
      |
      ---> Jamse---
      |           |
      |            ---> Level = 0
      ---> Taylor---
                  |
                  ----> Level = 1
```

I want traverse through every node and store the level number in the ArrayList. But the problem is that my ArrayList which is filled with level numbers can exist only inside of the firebaseListener function. Outside of the function, the ArrayList is empty. Can anyone give me an advice on how to fix this problem?

Code:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> parentLevel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_linked_people_tree);

        LinearLayout linked = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linkedlayoutid);

        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        users = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        parentLevel = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        mDatabaseReference.child("Users").child(users.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.child("OriginalUser").child("Parents").hasChildren()) {
                    DataSnapshot parentSnapshot = dataSnapshot;

                    int level = 0;
                    relatedParentNodeFinder(parentSnapshot, users.getUid(), level);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use the Arraylist outside of the callback? Your Arraylist can definitely exist outside of the listener. Please add your code

Comment: I added the code

Comment: parentLevel.add(level); adds the level number to the arraylist, but when I am trying to access it after the firebase listener in the main, it shows it as an emoty array

Comment: Where are you actually using the list?

Comment: I update the code, you can see the arrow

Comment: It shows an empty array because that listener isn't entered immediately where you write the code. You code move the list usage above the listener, and it's the basically the exact same code execution path on the main thread... You should put whatever list code at the end of the onDataChange, after the recursive method

Comment: parentLevel.add(level); is fine where it is

Comment: Well, the thing is that I am trying to store not every level number, but only ones with highest number in their branch. If I move the list outside of the recursive function, the code will save every level number in the array

Comment: You don't need to define the list inside the recursive method. You need to use it after the recursion has finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait for Firebase to run

```
    // clear onDataChange 
    parentLevel.clear();
    int level = 0;
    // populate the list 
    relatedParentNodeFinder(parentSnapshot, users.getUid(), level);
    // Use the list here. Shouldn't be empty 
}
```

Note that `level` will be zero after the node finder method

Comment: Ohh I understand what you are saying. I will have to keep using the arrayList inside of the onDataChange only

Comment: Yup, it did work that way. I guess I will have to keep it inside of the onDataChange. Thanks!

Comment: You can use the object reference as the field, but you need to just initialize the data within the callback, and wait for it to be populated